# AES Encryption/Decryption with key

Tags: java, android, cryptography, aes

1. Is this the best way to encrypt/decrypt data?
2. And Is it good to store Generated InitVector and CipherText in database as Base64 String which is converted from byte[]?

---

```
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.AlgorithmParameters;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Base64;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        //Encrypt
        EncryptHelper helper = new EncryptHelper();       
        EncryptedData a = helper.encrypt("key123", "This is the text to encrypt");

        //Decrypt
        EncryptHelper helper1 = new EncryptHelper();       
        String b = helper1.decrypt("key123", a);

        System.out.println(b);
    }



    public static class EncryptedData
    {
        String _saltString;
        String _initVector;
        String _cipherText;

        public EncryptedData(String saltString, String initVector, String cipherText)
        {
            _saltString = saltString;
            _initVector = initVector;
            _cipherText = cipherText;
        }

        public String getSaltString() { return _saltString; }
        public String getInitVector() { return _initVector; }
        public String getCipherText() { return _cipherText; }
    }

    public static class EncryptHelper
    {        
        public EncryptedData encrypt(String password, String data)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] salt = generateSalt();
                SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
                PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 65536, 256);
                SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
                SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

                /* Encrypt the message. */
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
                AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();

                byte[] initVector = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
                byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));

                return new EncryptedData(getBase64String(salt), getBase64String(initVector), getBase64String(ciphertext));
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        public String decrypt(String password, EncryptedData b)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] salt = getBase64Bytes(b.getSaltString());
                SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
                PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 65536, 256);
                SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
                SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

                //Get from EncryptedData
                byte[] initVector = getBase64Bytes(b.getInitVector());
                byte[] cipherText = getBase64Bytes(b.getCipherText());

                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(initVector));
                String plaintext = new String(cipher.doFinal(cipherText), "UTF-8");

                return plaintext;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.getMessage();
            }
        }

        private String getBase64String(byte[] data)
        {
            byte[] encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(data);

            return new String(encoded); 
        }

        private byte[] getBase64Bytes(String str)
        {
            return Base64.getDecoder().decode(str);
        }

        private byte[] generateSalt()
        {
            final Random r = new SecureRandom();
            byte[] salt = new byte[32];
            r.nextBytes(salt);

            return salt;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The easiest way to fix the formatting is probably to put a horizontal rule after the questions ( `----` ), delete the code, paste it in cleanly, select it, and press Ctrl-K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach might surely be to remove redundant code for the `SecretKey` and to add a default getter:

```
private static final String FACTORY_ALGORITHM = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256";
private static final String KEY_ALGORITHM = "AES";
private static final int KEYSPEC_ITERATION_COUNT = 65536;
private static final int KEYSPEC_LENGTH = 256;

//TODO describe your default implementation or use better member names (mine are a bit too plain - this would make this javadoc obsolete)
private SecretKey getDefaultSecretKey(final String password, final byte[] salt){
    return getSecretKey(password, salt, FACTORY_ALGORITHM, KEY_ALGORITHM, KEYSPEC_ITERATION_COUNT, KEYSPEC_LENGTH);
}

private SecretKey getSecretKey(final String password, 
        final byte[] salt, 
        final String factoryAlgorithm, 
        final String keyAlgorithm, 
        final int iterationCount, 
        final int keyLength){
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(factoryAlgorithm);
    return new SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, iterationCount, keyLength)).getEncoded(), keyAlgorithm); //thanks alot for the bug report
}
```

that would lead to a very readable version of your code:

```
public EncryptedData encrypt(String password, String data) throws Exception {
//you DONT handle Exceptions - so you let other people do the work you're supposed to do
//thats ok for me =)
    SecretKey secret = getDefaultSecretKey(password, generateSalt());
    Cipher cipher = getDefaulCipher(); //analogy towards getDefaultSecretKey - now you know how it would work
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
    AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();
    byte[] initVector = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
    byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8")); //FIXME: no hardcoded Byte-Conversion
    return new EncryptedData(getBase64String(salt), getBase64String(initVector), getBase64String(ciphertext));
}

public String decrypt(String password, EncryptedData b) throws Exception { 
//yeah exceptions handling is other peoples duty, not mine 
    SecretKey secret = getDefaultSecretKey(password, getBase64Bytes(b.getSaltString()));
    byte[] initVector = getBase64Bytes(b.getInitVector());
    byte[] cipherText = getBase64Bytes(b.getCipherText());
    Cipher cipher = getDefaulCipher(); //as mentioned above
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(initVector));
    return new String(cipher.doFinal(cipherText), "UTF-8"); //FIXME: no hardcoded Byte-Conversion
}
```

Things left (see comments in the code above):

- Improved exception handling;
- No hardcoded Byte-Conversion;
- Default getter for Cipher (following the example from `getDefaultSecretKey()`)

Comment: i hope you also managed to get the "Things left" done, they are important =) @DON

Comment: getDefaulCipher missing

Comment: java:63: error: incompatible types: SecretKey cannot be converted to byte[]
            return new SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, iterationCount, keyLength)), keyAlgorithm);

Comment: it's always hard for me, i don't copy&paste this code into an IDE i just write from brain into codereview.stackexchange.com - thank you for taking my adviceds for real!!

Comment: and what about getDefaultCipher?, Sorry I could not figure that out

Comment: please compile once and check..

Comment: i would have expected you to write `getDefaultCipher()` on your own. if you insist i can add... but you would loose the benefit of the exercise. let me know if you cannot handle `getDefaultCipher()`, then i'll add it!

Comment: private Cipher getDefaultCipher()
        {
          return  Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        }

Comment: hey wait! THOU SHALLST NOT USE HARDCODED CONSTANTS =) define a variable `private static final String CIPHER_METHODE = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";`and refer to it!

Comment: hahahaha =) don't listen to me!